# Emergency storage for java

Tags: java, performance, storage, mapdb

I am writing transport adapter for the messages(I receive the message from java native methods and send it to the RabbitMQ's queue) and I mustn't lose any messages(For example the connection to RabbitMQ's server is unavailable). I need an persistence storage for my messages when process or send it was failed. Now I use mapDB library and its queue implementation

```
public void send(byte[] message){
    queue.add(message);
    db.commit();
    //do process and send the message
    queue.poll();//message sent success, we can remove it from storage
    db.commit();
}
```

But it implementation doing very long. Please advice the best implementation for this case.

The message must be in the right order.

Comment: Q: What's "long"?  Q: Have you benchmarked alternatives to mapDB?

Comment: please give more details

Comment: Q: Is it important to get the messages in the right order? We need much more informations

Comment: The message must be in the right order. I don't have benchmark for alternatives therefore I ask you about it. I need your expirience

Comment: RAM storage being 10 times faster than persistent storage is not weird. Just go with your current implementation.

Comment: Where is `t` coming from?

Comment: And what if the database is down? Your memory goes corrupt? Or your entire server dies? The way to guarantee message delivery is not to add more backup routes. That just increases the chances. For actual guarantees, the entire system must be designed so that the sender is able to send again when it doesn't get an ack that the message was delivered. Like they do it in mqtt for example http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels

Comment: Taking the problem at the tail: maybe make the sending transactional, with a commit/rollback/persistence log.